# Syntax error in a Google Analytics onclick event

Tags: wordpress, syntax, onclick

I am trying to insert an ad between 1st and 2nd posts on my blog and when I enter the following code in functions.php (within Wordpress), it gives a syntax error:

syntax error, unexpected 'event' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

I've looked at it a hundred times and can't find anything wrong. I also use the same onclick code on post pages and it works, but functions.php won't let me save unless I correct it.

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'ad_on_home' );
function ad_on_home() {
    global $loop_counter;
    if( $loop_counter == 1 ) {
        echo '<div style="margin-bottom:35px;">
        <ins><h5>AD</h5><a href="https://example.com" onclick="gtag('event', 'Click', { 'event_category': 'Outbound Link', 'event_action':'Click','event_label’:’Post Banner' });" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/banner3.jpg" alt=“Banner” width="1000" height="190" /></a>/ins></div>';
        $loop_counter_paged = $loop_counter_paged + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First time, you have not closed the `<ins></ins>` tag.

After you have an error in "event_label" :

- Replace `'event_label’:’Post Banner'`
- By `'event_label':'Post Banner'`

It's all for me :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I've made those changes, but I'm still getting the same error: syntax error, unexpected 'event' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I narrowed it down to the following code. It works without the onclick part. But when I add the following, it gives a syntax error: onclick="gtag('event', 'Click', { 'event_category': 'Outbound Link', 'event_action':'Click','event_label’:’Post Banner' });"

Comment: You have not completly follow my comment. You have yet the ’ symbol in place of ' symbol in "event label"